# T-SQL to Postgres wildcard logic

Tags: postgresql, t-sql

I am in the process of converting some t-sql queries to postgres and I am having trouble wrapping my head around the postgres wildcard logic.

eg:

The following query in tsql will yeild 'A' however in postgres it returns 'B'

```
    Select 
    case when 'abcd 1234' like '%[a-z]%[0-9]%' then 'A' else 'B' end as Q1
```

What would be the postgres equivalent to the above case when statement?
Furthermore, does anyone have a general rule of thumb for converting tsql string logic to postgres ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference that you're running into here is that SQL Server's TSQL accepts character range wildcards through the square bracket `[]` syntax but PostgreSQL does not.

Instead, PostgreSQL incorporates support for POSIX regular expressions within a query using the RegEx match operators - variations of `~` - in place of `LIKE` and offer quite a bit of flexibility with respect to case sensitivity and string-matching.

Restating your original query in a POSIX RegEx syntax to achieve an output of 'A' will resemble this:

```
  Select 
    case when 'abcd 1234' ~ '(.*)[a-z](.*)[0-9](.*)' then 'A' 
    else 'B' end as Q1
```

As for the notion of general heuristics for handling these sorts of conversions, I would suggest that T-SQL character-set wildcards should be implemented as POSIX regular expressions using the RegEx match operator rather than `LIKE`. Otherwise, the T-SQL `%` and `_` wildcards behave equivalently to the same PostgreSQL wildcards.

References:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15
- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#LIKE
- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#POSIX-BRACKET-EXPRESSIONS

Comment: Just as a side note: the SQL standard only defines the wildcards `%` and `_` for the LIKE operator and nothing else. This is not specific to Postgres. SQL Server's support for "regex like" wildcards in T-SQL is non-standard

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name That's an important note! Thank you for that and the edit for the current doc URL (I wasn't watching closely)